# How to size the fuse in this case?

Tags: power-supply, fuses

Inside an enclosure, [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/4a7c/0900766b814e420a.pdf) PSU(12V, 12.5A) powers all the electrical devices such as DC fans and some other DC operated devices. So basically the PSU powers everything and needs to source 8A continuously. The AC power only feeds the PSU.

AC power outlet --> IEC connector --> PSU --> DC powered devices

The thing is I use [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/cba3/0900766b815867ba.pdf) IEC connector to power the PSU. An this connector requires a fuse.

In my case, is the fuse type and rating relevant? How can I roughly size the required fuse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This RS part: -

[image]

Is rated at 6 amps maximum and the inrush current of the Mean Well power supply has a cold-start inrush current of 60 amps: -

[image]

That's what I'd focus on and not the fuse rating (although it does need to be adequately rated. In other words, I'd be seriously concerned about the rocker switch on the RS part and its ability to survive a few cycles on cold start with burning.

Comment: What do you mean by cold start?  Thanks

Comment: Cold start means when the power supply (Mean Well) is turned **ON** after being off for a few minutes or more.

Comment: Omg does that mean it typically peaks to around 60A current(for a very short time) almost each time after being some time off? It is very difficult to make comparison here. 60A is a very short time current but the rocker switch's rating only given for steady state.

Comment: One last question: The switch spec given as: 6Amp, 250VAC. But If this is to be used in a country with 110VAC would that make any difference in rated current?

Comment: You can't rely on the rocker switch given the information in the data sheets. When operated at lower voltages, the Mean Well power supply will take more regular operational current (2.8 amps at 115 VAC vs 1.6 amps at 230 VAC) but the inrush current will be about half the amount @user1999 - I wouldn't use the two together even on an input supply of  only 115 VAC.

Comment: If I use this inlet, would a 100nf line rated capacitor prevent the arc and save the switch from inrush current in this case?

Comment: I also opened another question here related https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/577225/why-do-input-power-calculations-for-this-power-supply-do-not-match

Comment: @user1999 are you not upvoting answers that are useful to you? Have you forgotten what makes this site work? I can't see any capacitor placed anywhere helping with this problem. It's the Mean Well power supplies internal DC capacitors that are actually causing the massive inrush.

Answer (score 0):

Mean Wells are notorious for their bad inrush currents. Too bad they don't say for *how much* the inrush is. *Usually* 50ms is a conservative duration (since the inrush is exponentially decaying)

You definitely want a T (delayed or slow blow fuse). Pick your favourite brand or standard (like IEC fuses, for example) and look at the I2s curves: you want to survive the surge and the running current (so you need to stay *on the left* of the curve) but the safety limit (i.e. cable and connector rating) should be on the right of the curve.

As an example, the Littelfuse 213 (IEC delayed) at 3.15A has a thermal limit of about 6A (so in a pitch would be *just enough* to protect the connector, but no safety margin) and can handle 60A for about 20ms so it's a little too small (you risk thermal fatigue and nuisance tripping). A 5A IEC fuse instead will keep running 10A for hours so it would burn the connector.

There's just no 'standard' fuse fitting the bill, here (also remember that fuses are not precision components, they have tolerances).

In this case you can either a) use a bigger inlet module (rated 10A, for example) or b) use an inrush limiter (these are special NTCs but are somewhat tricky to apply correctly)

In my opinion just use a bigger input module

Comment: If I use this inlet, would a 100nf line rated capacitor prevent the arc and save the switch from inrush current in this case?

Comment: no, that wouldn't save you from the inrush. A rated RC snubber could help for the arc but for the inrush you'd need something like these https://product.tdk.com/en/products/protection/current/ntc-limiter/index.html; study the application notes carefully